# Why is my intuition about probability in this regard so flawed?

Tags: probability, intuition

Take the following example:

Take a sample from 100 people and measure their height. Assume that we know that height is approximately normally distributed, with a sample mean of 175 cm and sample standard deviation of 3.

Why is it so intuitive for me to think that the most probable distribution of height just based on this observation is a normal distribution with parameters (175,3)?

The probability of observing this sample is 0 and that is for all parameter pairs. Why do I still intuitively think that this distribution is the most probable one?

Comment: One issue seems to be that for a continuous distribution the probability of getting any specified precise value is $0$ even if the probability of being close to a specified value is positive.  This is not just an issue for a normal distribution, and leads to the idea of a probability density which is possible to maximise.

Comment: @Henry Is that still the case when we accept that the heights can only be measured with finite precision? Say to the nearest cm, or mm. Don't we then need to use a discrete approximation of the normal?

Comment: The probability of observing that sample in NOT zero. You cannot measure height with the infinite precision required to make the probabilities become infinitesimal.